# Get shape by geometry ID

Tags: drake

How do you get the shape by geometry ID?

For example, using this code to create shapes:

```
def AddShape(plant, shape, name, mass=1, mu=1, color=[.5, .5, .9, 1.0], position=np.zeros(3),
             rot_matrix=RotationMatrix(np.eye(3))):
    instance = plant.AddModelInstance(name)
    # TODO: Add a method to UnitInertia that accepts a geometry shape (unless
    # that dependency is somehow gross) and does this.
    if isinstance(shape, pydrake.geometry.Box):
        inertia = pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia.SolidBox(
            shape.width(), shape.depth(), shape.height())
    elif isinstance(shape, pydrake.geometry.Cylinder):
        inertia = pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia.SolidCylinder(
            shape.radius(), shape.length())
    elif isinstance(shape, pydrake.geometry.Sphere):
        inertia = pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia.SolidSphere(shape.radius())
    else:
        # raise RunTimeError(
        #     f"need to write the unit inertia for shapes of type {shape}")
        inertia = pydrake.multibody.tree.UnitInertia.SolidBox(
            1, 1, 1)
        print("inertia not defined, using unit cube inertia")

    if isinstance(rot_matrix, np.ndarray):
        # TODO normalize
        # quaternion = quaternion / np.linalg.norm(quaternion)
        H = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix(rot_matrix), position)
    else:
        H = RigidTransform(rot_matrix, position)

    body = plant.AddRigidBody(
        name, instance,
        SpatialInertia(mass=mass,
                       p_PScm_E=np.array([0., 0., 0.]),
                       G_SP_E=inertia))

    if plant.geometry_source_is_registered():
        if isinstance(shape, pydrake.geometry.Box):
            geom_id = plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
                body, H,
                pydrake.geometry.Box(shape.width() - 0.001,
                                     shape.depth() - 0.001,
                                     shape.height() - 0.001), name,
                pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction(mu, mu))
            i = 0

            print("Line 185: Ignoring box collision geometry for now...")
            # for x in [-shape.width() / 2.0, shape.width() / 2.0]:
            #     for y in [-shape.depth() / 2.0, shape.depth() / 2.0]:
            #         for z in [-shape.height() / 2.0, shape.height() / 2.0]:
            #             plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
            #                 body, H.multiply(RigidTransform([x, y, z])),
            #                 pydrake.geometry.Sphere(radius=1e-7),
            #                 f"contact_sphere{i}",
            #                 pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction(mu, mu))
            #             i += 1
        else:
            geom_id = plant.RegisterCollisionGeometry(
                body, H, shape, name,
                pydrake.multibody.plant.CoulombFriction(mu, mu))
    # else:
        # raise NotImplementedError

    plant.RegisterVisualGeometry(body, H, shape, name, color)

    return instance, geom_id, body
```

Then later on in our code, suppose we have access to geom_id, how do we know whether it was originally a Sphere, Convex, Mesh, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The outline of the answer is to use [SceneGraphInspector](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.SceneGraphInspector).

To get an instance of that object, you need to decide whether you want the *model* scene (the one created during parsing & setup) or a *context* scene (a copy in the Context, distinct from the model). For the *model* scene, call [pydrake.geometry.SceneGraph.model_inspector](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.SceneGraph.model_inspector) on the SceneGraph.  For the *context* scene, call [pydrake.geometry.QueryObject.inspector](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.QueryObject.inspector) on a QueryObject obtained from a Context.

Once you have an inspector, you can call [SceneGraphInspector.GetShape](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.geometry.html#pydrake.geometry.SceneGraphInspector.GetShape) to get the shape back.  It will have a runtime type like `geometry.Box`.